# What would cause intermittent EC2 > RDS host resolution issues?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-rds

The issue is an inability to resolve the DB host but it's not persistent.

Environment:

AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04

connecting to:

MYSQL 5.7 RDS

This started just after an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
It works probably 99/100 tries, but then fails and throws this exception: `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`.

Comment: If you are running on T2 instance type, check your CPU credits. Once you run out of credits, your performance will drop thru the floor. This includes networking. At 0 credits even logins will start to take extended times or fail.

Comment: My CPU credits are good. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears amazon supplies a local DNS server for your EC2 instance. I believe it has a request limit which causes failure if you go over it. My fix was to add this file: "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail;" with the contents "nameserver 1.1.1.1" basically setting 1.1.1.1 as my fallback DNS server. It's a bit slower since it's outside the network, but it's better than a complete failure.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-limits

Comment: Shane, do you have a AWS link for your answer? I am not disputing your answer. I have just never seen this for AWS services.

Comment: Updated answer to include

Comment: Shane, if I'm not mistaken, this will fail because external DNS servers will not be able to resolve AWS internal names for RDS instances, no?

Comment: Nah, my RDS is publicly resolvable.

Comment: It's not different than using the RDS hostname from your local machine to connect and make changes using a MYSQL client - Unless you VPN or SSH to connect - which I don't.

Comment: @ShaneStebner I am facing the same issue, and was looking at your suggestion. In my etc, I have resolv.conf but no directory resolveconf. Could you please help on how to go about in my case?